# Delegate method not called properly

Tags: ios, swift, methods, delegates, protocols

I am using a Service class where a protocol is declared. This protocol is implemented by two viewcontrollers, i.e. `DashboardVC` and `DashboardDetailVC`. Protocol works fine when called from `DashboardVC`. Then in `DashboardDetailVC` also, it works fine calling protocol method defined in `DashboardDetailVC`. BUT, when I dismiss `DashboardDetailVC` and move back to `DashboardVC`, then protocol method of `DashboardDetailVC` is called. My code is:

**Service.swift**

```
protocol DashboardDelegate {
  func dashboardInfoResponse(data: [String: Any])
}

class Service {
  var dashboardDelegate: DashboardDelegate?

  func hitWebRequest(api: String, request: URLRequest) {
    ..
    self.dashboardDelegate?.dashboardInfoResponse(data: dataArray)
    ..
  }
}
```

**DashboardVC.swift**

```
class DashboardVC: DashboardDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Service.shared().dashboardDelegate = self
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    Service.shared().dashboardInfo(postData: token)

}

func dashboardInfoResponse(data: [String : Any]) {
  ..
  ..
}
```

**DashboardDetailVC.swift**

```
class DashboardDetailVC: DashboardDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Service.shared().dashboardDelegate = self
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    Service.shared().dashboardInfo(postData: token)

}

func dashboardInfoResponse(data: [String : Any]) {
  ..
  ..
}
```

When I go back from `DashboardDetailVC` to `DashboardVC` using

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

protocol method from `DashboardVC` is called, But still it returns to `dashboardInfoResponse` protocol method in `DashboardDetailVC`.

Comment: maybe after your dismiss detail VC, the delegate sign not changed back, viewDidLoad method may not run every time, only the time need the "load" job, that is the case, delegate property was not overwrite as you need

Comment: yes, that was the issue, thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is obvious  You have class `Service` which has `sharedInstance` that means only single object is been used in whole application cycle.. And only single delegate property been shared among all.

Observe that

`DashboardVC` in `viewDidLoad`  you set `delegate` to `self`  that means it is pointing to  `DashboardVC`

After that you present `DashboardDetailVC` you set `delegate` to `self`  that means it is pointing to  `DashboardDetailVC`

and after that your all delegate call will go to  `DashboardDetailVC` not to  `DashboardVC` even though you dismiss VC

To fix this: You have options.

1) Don't use Shared Instance

2) set delegate in `ViewWillAppear` instead.

3) Use NotificationCenter and post notification

Hope it is helpful to you

Comment: Thanks @Prashant, delegate surely needs to be assigned to self in 'ViewWillAppear' as I'm using Singleton.

Comment: @omi23 Welcome Happy Coding :)

Comment: @omi23 Why you reverse your vote ? is solution not helpful to you ?

Comment: oh, I double clicked, my bad

Comment: @omi23 Not an issue , Thanks for accepting answer :)

Answer (score -1):

if you override viewWillAppear , yourView.delegate=self not work for that. you have to identify your .delegate=self on override method